# Encoding and Decoding UTF-8 and latin1

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I'm studying someone's code for processing data, and got errors on this line:

```
chars_sst_mangled = ['à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'æ', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'í', 
'í', 'ï', 'ñ', 'ó', 'ô', 'ö', 'û', 'ü']
sentence_fixups = [(char.encode('utf-8').decode('latin1'), char) for char in chars_sst_mangled]
```

The error message is

```
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"
```

I wonder what's the problem here, and how to fix it?

Comment: It seems that you are running this snippet in python 2.X. And since the `encode()` method is for converting a unicode to byte and you are attempting to convert a sequence of byte (encoded character) to byte python raises this error, for getting ride of this problem you can use `decode()` method, to convert the string (raw 8bit values) to unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is broken.

The specific error indicates that you are trying to run Python 3 code using python2 executable:

```
>>> 'à'.encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

`'à'` is a bytestring on Python 2 and therefore calling `.encode()` method requires to decode the bytestring into Unicode first. It is done using `sys.getdefaultencoding()` that is `'ascii'` in Python 2 that triggers the `UnicodeDecodeError`.

The correct way would be to drop bogus `char.encode('utf-8').decode('latin1')` conversion and use Unicode literals instead:

- add the correct encoding declaration e.g., if the source file is saved using utf-8 encoding then put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top so that non-ascii characters in string literals hardcoded in the source would be interpreted correctly
- also, add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` so that `'à'` would create a Unicode string even on Python 2.